# Differentiable function and polynomials: Proof of $\phi (x)=ce^x + q(x)$ unclear to me.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I came across a proof which I can't quite understand:

If $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function with $\phi'=\phi+p$, there exists a polynomial $q$ of degree $n$ with a number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\phi(x)=ce^x+q(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The proof is given as follows:

$$\phi'=\phi+p$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\phi'-\phi = p$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\phi'*e^{-x}-\phi*e^{-x}=p*e^{-x}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)[\phi*e^{-x}]=p*e^{-x}$$
$$\int\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)[\phi*e^{-x}]=\int p*e^{-x}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\phi*e^{-x}=q*e^{-x}+c$$
$$\Rightarrow\phi(x)=ce^x+q(x)$$

Isn't the notation (especially the integrals) missing something?

Why exactly are we multiplying by $e^{-x}$ in line 3? Is this a special technique?

How does the integral with $p$ in it suddenly yield $q$? And why is the arbitrary constant $c$ on the left hand side of the equation missing?

Also, the conclusion is unclear to me. How exactly do the $e^{-x}$ and $c$ disappear and how does the $ce^x$ appear?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you remember the product rule from calculus ? Using that we have $${d \over dx} \left( \phi*e^{-x}\right) = {d \over dx}\phi*e^{-x}+{d \over dx}{e^{-x}}*\phi$$

Is the motivation of why we multiplied $e^{-x}$ to the equation.

The reason why $p$ sudenly seems like it turned into a $q$, is because you integrated

$$\int p(x)*e^{-x}dx = q(x)*e^{-x}+c$$

Here, when you integrate the polynomial becomes something different.
For example using integration by parts,$$\int x*e^{-x}dx = -(1+x)e^{-x}+c$$

where $p(x) = x$ and $q(x)=-(1+x)$

Finally, the reason why it seems like $e^{-x}$ suddenly dissapeared, is because it hasn't. When we look at the very last step, all it's doing is multiplying $e^x$ on both sides. And $e^{-x}*e^x = 1$.

Does this help ?

Comment: It does, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. You can click the left check mark so that we can see that you accept the answer. It really motivates us :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why exactly are we multiplying by $e^{−x}$ in line 3:

The OE $$\phi'(x)-\phi(x) = p(x)$$ is a *Linear differential equation of first degree* and as an method we need a magic function called *[Integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)* to solve it. The method tells us to multiply this given function to the OE, both sides of it, just to make the OE an *[exact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation)* OE. Here we have $-1$ as the coefficient of $\phi(x)$ in OE, so according to cited approach the integrating factor is: $$\mu(x)=\exp\int(-1)dx=\text{e}^{-x}$$ Now continue from line 3 to the rest.

> How does the integral with p in it suddenly yield $q$?

Do as @nullUser noted, he did the rest complete.

Comment: nice write up too! +1

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The notation is quite abusive. The author assumes the reader is familiar enough with differential equations to understand what the notation means, where the $dx$'s go and so on.

We multiply by $e^{-x}$ because we recognize the ODE $y'-y = p$ to be first order linear, which can always be solved by multiplying by a suitable integrating factor, which in this case turns out to be $e^{-x}$. See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx for examples.

The statement $\int p(x) e^{-x}dx = q(x)e^{-x}+c$ follows by induction from the fact that $\int x^k e^{-x}dx$ is solved by repeated integration by parts. Differentiating powers of $x$ and integrating $e^{-x}$ always leaves you with a term of the form $x^n e^{-x}$ up to a multiplicative constant.

To get the last line from its predecessor just multiply the equation by $e^{x}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This explanation was very helpful.